# Updating CurrentValues() on an entity with a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EFCore 1.1.0 in a netstandard1.6 application.

I have configured my model with a composite key

```
public class ClassExtension
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public MyClass Class { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassExtension> Extensions { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        Extensions = new List<ClassExtension>();
    }
}
```

Then in my dbcontext OnModelCreating()

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassExtension>()
   .HasKey(p => new { p.Id, p.ClassId });
```

I then get from the database the existing instance of a particular composite key, then create a new instance of ClassExtension in code based on user input and finally assign those values to the entity then save it.

```
var existingSpec = await db.ClassSpecs.Where(
    c => c.ClassId == existingClass.Id && c.Id == input.Id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var newExtension = new ClassExtension()
{
    Id = input.Id,
    Name = input.Name
};

db.Entry(existingSpec).CurrentValues.SetValues(newSpec); // Errors on this line
db.Entry(existingSpec).Property(p => p.ClassId).IsModified = false;
await db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

The application generates the following error when trying to assign the values using SetValues()

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ClassId' on entity type 'ClassExtension' 
is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.
... removed ...
at MyApplication...
```

When I do this on a table without a composite key it works just fine, not overwriting the existing foreign key Id with null, just using its existing value.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this just a quirk with using composite keys?

Comment: Apparently you need to set the PK values before calling `SetValues` - e.g. `new ClassExtension { Id = existingSpec.Id, ClassId = existingSpec.ClassId, Name = input.Name, ... }`